# Hot Corners and dual screens

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8

Is there any way to have Hot Corners only activate on the outer most corners of a dual screen set up?

It's quite off putting having the settings sidebar pop up every time I try and close something on my left hand monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about turning off the charms bar on the inside edges, but you can stop the 'catching' of the mouse in the corner which eliminated the issue for me. So maybe this will help?

You can get around hot corners with a simple registry change, it just stops the mouse catching.

**In registry, search: MouseCornerClipLength 

Set the value to 0 (from 6). 

Repeat (there is more than one key with this name, I'm not sure which one(s) are necessary).
 
Restart.**

You can still use the charms bar without issue on the outside edge of your monitors as easily as before (exactly as I wanted).

I created a thread a while ago about this here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-desktop/how-to-disable-hot-corners-on-dual-screen/69b45244-ffc7-4ac7-8473-d69c3799245b?msgId=8d4d2be9-7878-4a76-8429-0087ae27750b&page=2